# Are there any whacky orderings of R?

Tags: analysis

Is there any way to reorder R so that 3 < 2?
And a similar question, which probably can be answered in the same breath:
Is d(2, 3) < d(2, 100) for all metrics? 
Is there a nice theorem that talks about this?

Comment: Can't reorder in a way that "plays nice" with the algebra.

Comment: You can wellorder it, but you won't be able to say exactly what such an order looks like.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the helpful remarks, it is much clearer now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Put $3$ at the front, $2$ at the back, all the rest in between, ordered among themselves in the usual way (or any way you like).
2. An easy way to get a metric on $\mathbb R$ satisfying $d(2,3)\gt d(2,100)$ is to identify $\mathbb R$ with a suitably bent curve in the plane and use the planar distance. E.g., define $$z(t)=e^{(\pi i-1)t}$$ and then define $$d(s,t)=|z(s)-z(t)|=|e^{(\pi i-1)s}-e^{(\pi i-1)t}|;$$ then $$d(2,3)=e^{-2}+e^{-3}\gt e^{-2}$$ while $$d(2,100)=e^{-2}-e^{-100}\lt e^{-2}\lt d(2,3).$$

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes: define $x\prec y$ if and only if $x>y$ in the usual ordering.
2. No, not even for metrics generating the usual topology: define $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1\}$.

Comment: Brian problem is that does not order f as a field. You end up having -1>0 but then (-1)^2>0 so 1>0 and hence 0>(0-1) 0>-1 this is a contradiction. If you just want to order it as a set there are of course infinitely many ordering I mean we can use your thing but rather then inverting all of R all we need to do is invert interval [2,3].

Comment: @Anthony: The OP did not impose any algebraic requirements on the order.

Answer (score 0):

Given a ring $R$ let $f(a,b,c)$ be a value in the set $\{-1, 1\}$.  Then define the ordering so that $f(a,b,c) c\cdot a \lt f(a,b,c) c\cdot b$ whenever $a \lt b$.  Do a similar thing for addition.